# ERROR in @ViewChild options must be an object literal in angular 9

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular9, viewchild, angular-upgrade

I have upgraded my Angular project from Angular version 8 to Angular version 9. it was upgraded successfully but when I am running the project on localhost or when I am trying to build my project it is giving me the following error.

```
ERROR in @ViewChild options must be an object literal
```

here is my @ViewChild syntax in some files that I am using.

```
  @ViewChild('subjectbox',null) private elementRefsub: ElementRef;
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

can anyone please help with this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Remove `, null` from `@ViewChild('subjectbox', null)` and initialize the ref to an empty object. 
`@ViewChild('subjectbox') private elementRefsub: ElementRef = {} as ElementRef;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not need a metadata, you can write:

```
@ViewChild('subjectbox') private elementRefsub: ElementRef;
```

Metadata Properties: (examples for properties listed for your reference)

**selector - The directive type or the name used for querying.**

**read - Used to read a different token from the queried elements.**

```
@ViewChild('subjectbox', { read: ElementRef }) private elementRefsub: ElementRef;
```

**static - True to resolve query results before change detection runs, false to resolve after change detection. Defaults to false.**

```
@ViewChild('subjectbox', { static: false }) private elementRefsub: ElementRef;
```